# Marshal Delegate to std::function

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Can this be done?

Marshalling to a C-style function pointer can be done with the following code:

```
GCHandle rahHandlle = GCHandle::Alloc(reAuthHandler);
IntPtr rahPtr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(reAuthHandler);
auto rahUnman = static_cast<SomeFuncPtr>(rahPtr.ToPointer());
```

But how would one marshal to a std::function? If it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

Declare a function pointer in your C++/CLI .NET code which matches the parameters in your native std::function - and cast the pointer of the .NET delegate to this.

```
//C++ CLI
IntPtr rahPtr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(reAuthHandler);

//Declare a function pointer which matches the parameters of your native C++ std::function
typedef void(__stdcall * ThisIsMyCppFunctionDeclaration)(long);

//Then cast your delegate pointer to the c++ function pointer (which
auto callbackFunctionCpp = static_cast<ThisIsMyCppFunctionDeclaration>(rahPtr.ToPointer());

//And then finally invoke your native C++ method which takes a std::function
DoWork(callbackFunctionCpp);
```

-

```
//C++ Native
void DoWork(std::function<void(long theLongValue)> callback){
    //Do something
    callback(123);
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!